Book about a guy who claimed to only ever bowl perfect games
I'm looking for a book I remember reading as a child, about 15 years ago.
The basic premise is a person who gets a job at a bowling alley, and becomes friends with the owner, who claims to have only ever bowled perfect 300 games.
Near the end of the book, the owner reveals the reason he has a perfect record is because he never actually played.  By the end the protagonist encourages him to actually play a game, and he bowls a perfect 300.

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make this work easier to identify, please add any information you have of the kind listed at the tag wiki for identification requests. This includes details about where you read it, what the publication date seemed to be, what the book looked like, etc. Please edit your question to add these details, don't provide them in the comments. Thanks!
